# Code to Calculate Minimum Monthly Credit Card Repayment Over A year

Tags: python

Please I am trying to find out what is wrong with my reasoning, and hence my results.
I am studying an online course where I am supposed to calculate the minimum figure needed to eliminate credit card debt over 12 months. I am given an annual interest rate, a value for the amount of debt (balance), and a value by which the monthly payments should increase (multiples of 10) only.
From my reasoning, my code generated should iterate over the months, but if the balance value is not zero, it should increase the monthly payments and recalculate.
My values are (I think) just slightly off of the expected results. My code is like this:

```
annualInterestRate = 0.2
monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 12.0
monthlyPayment = 10

while (balance > 0):

    for each in range(0, 12):
        balance = balance - monthlyPayment
        balance = balance + (monthlyInterestRate * balance)
        if (balance > 0):
            monthlyPayment += 10
        else:
            break

print monthlyPayment
```

For balance = 3329, annual interest rate of 0.2,
My result is: 310 (correct)

For balance = 4773, annual interest rate of 0.2,
My result is: 380 (incorrect, should be 440)

For balance = 3926, annual interest rate of 0.2,
My result is: 340 (incorrect, should be 360).

Please can someone help enlighten me where I am wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `My result is: 360 (incorrect, should be 360).` ?

Comment: Shouldn't if(balance > 0) be at the same level as the for each, instead of inside the for each?

Comment: I get an infinite loop when I do that, @Aziuth.

Comment: @OverlordQ, sorry typo, fixed.

Comment: @Sina: But what you want to do is to iterate over possible values of monthlyPayment, right? So it should be like while(monthlyPayment insufficient): reset balance, test if monthlyPayment correct, increase monthlyPayment if not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. There are a few problems in your implementation.

First off, you need to reset the balance after realizing the previously tested monthly payment didn't, well, pay out.

Secondly, the tabbing where you check the balance and increase it is wrong. As it stands, you pay 10 more dollars a month each month, which if I'm understanding your question properly is not what you want. You want to increase the monthly payment *after* seeing the one 10 dollars less didn't pay it off in 12 months.

Just as another point, your `else: break` is unnecessary as it will break out of the `while` loop when it enters into the next iteration.

```
startBalance = int(input("what's the stating balance? "))
balance = startBalance
numMonths = 12

annualInterestRate = 0.2
monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 12.0
monthlyPayment = 10

while (balance > 0):
    balance = startBalance # reset the balance each iteration

    print('checking monthly payment of',monthlyPayment)
    for each in range(0, numMonths):
        balance = balance - monthlyPayment
        balance = balance + (monthlyInterestRate * balance)
        # print('at month',each,'the balance is',balance)

    # changed the indentation below
    if (balance > 0):
        monthlyPayment += 10

print('you should pay',monthlyPayment,'per month')
```

Comment: His break is necessary for his results to be as close as they are to the correct answer. If not, he would have had a more apparent bug.

Comment: Hah, yes good point. And as you pointed out, the whole `if` statement is redundant inside the `while` loop, anyhow, if `monthlyPayment += 10` is at it's start with `monthlyPayment` initialized at 0. I kept it to make clear that the original code is increasing the payment by 10 *every month* and not just when the previous test fails.

Answer (score 1):

1. The balance payed should be the same for the entire year so the `if` inside the `for each` doesn't make sense. The `if` isn't needed.
2. The balance needs to be reset to the starting value when trying out a new monthly payment.

I tried it with these changes and it matches your test cases.

Comment: Please how do I do this? I'm not sure I understand you properly.

Comment: @Sina pirt has given you a complete answer. I'd get rid of the if completely though. Initialize `monthlyPayment = 0` and move `monthlyPayment+=10`  to just inside the while.  The if is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
annualInterestRate = 0.2
monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 12.0
monthlyPayment = 10
running = true;

while (running):

    currentBalance = balance

    for each in range(0, 12):
        currentBalance = currentBalance - monthlyPayment
        currentBalance = currentBalance + (monthlyInterestRate * currentBalance)
    if (currentBalance > 0):
        monthlyPayment += 10
    else:
        running = false

print monthlyPayment
```

What I essentially did was getting the if-condition out of the for-each, with a copy for balance used. while(running) essentially iterates over possible values for monthlyPayment.

(you could go with while(currentBalance > 0) if currentBalance is set earlier, but I'd go with my while(running) approach so it is read like a do-until-loop)

Comment: Thanks a lot Aziuth. Your comments and your code really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Outstanding = 59400 # Total Outstanding Amount
interestrate = 4.2  # Interest Rate per month+ GST

#print("Month", "\t", "Interest+GST", "\t\t", "MinAmtDue", "\t\t\t", "Balance")
#print("-----", "\t\t", "-------", "\t\t", "--------", "\t\t\t", "-------")

month = 0
totpmt = 0
interest_GST = 0
minamtdue = 0
outstandingamt1 = Outstanding
while (outstandingamt1 + interest_GST - minamtdue) > 0 :
    month += 1
    interest_GST = outstandingamt1*4.2/100
    minamtdue = outstandingamt1 * 5/100
    #minamtdue = 12000
    outstandingamt1 = outstandingamt1 + interest_GST - minamtdue
    #print(month, "\t\t\t", round(interest_GST,2), "\t\t", round(minamtdue,2), "\t\t\t", round(outstandingamt1,2))
    totpmt = totpmt + minamtdue
#print(month+1, "\t\t\t", 0, "\t\t", round(outstandingamt1,2), "\t\t\t", 0)
print("Total Amount to be paid in ", month+1, "months= ", round(totpmt+outstandingamt1 , 2))
```