# Finding minimum payment for credit card to be paid in 1 year with python

Tags: python

I am trying to finish this problem. I'm getting stuck doing the code two different ways. My code is not increasing the payment enough to cover paying off the entire balance. I'll post my two versions that I got stuck on. Could someone offer what I am missing?

> Now write a program that calculates the minimum fixed monthly payment
>   needed in order pay off a credit card balance within 12 months. By a
>   fixed monthly payment, we mean a single number which does not change
>   each month, but instead is a constant amount that will be paid each
>   month.
>
> In this problem, we will not be dealing with a minimum monthly payment
>   rate.
>
> The following variables contain values as described below:
>
> balance - the outstanding balance on the credit card
>
> annualInterestRate - annual interest rate as a decimal
>
> The program should print out one line: the lowest monthly payment that
>   will pay off all debt in under 1 year, for example:
>
> Lowest Payment: 180  Assume that the interest is compounded monthly
>   according to the balance at the end of the month (after the payment
>   for that month is made). The monthly payment must be a multiple of $10
>   and is the same for all months. Notice that it is possible for the
>   balance to become negative using this payment scheme, which is okay. A
>   summary of the required math is found below:
>
> Monthly interest rate = (Annual interest rate) / 12.0 Monthly unpaid
>   balance = (Previous balance) - (Minimum fixed monthly payment) Updated
>   balance each month = (Monthly unpaid balance) + (Monthly interest rate
>   x Monthly unpaid balance)

Function 1, which I can't figure out to get it to get the right payment within 12 months

```
def cardBalance(balance,annualInterestRate,fixedPayment,months):        
    while True:
        for month in range(months):
            balace = (balance - fixedPayment) * (1 + (annualInterestRate/12))
            if balance > 0:
                fixedPayment += 10
            else:
                break
        return('Lowest Payment: ' + str(round(fixedPayment,0)))
cardBalance(399,.2,0,12)
# returns lowest payment of 120, balance remains 293.8
```

Function 2, which i can't figure out how to fix

```
balance = 100
balanceToPay = (balance / months)
annualInterestRate = .05
interestRate = (annualInterestRate / 12.00) 
payment = 0
minPayment = payment * balance

month = 0
totalPayment = 0

for i in range(0,13):
    if month < 12:
        month += 1
        if balance >= 0:
            payment += 10
            balance = balance - payment
            balance = balance + (balance * interestRate)
        else:
            if balance < 0:
                break
    else:
        return ('Lowest Payment: ' + str(payment))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code to Calculate Minimum Monthly Credit Card Repayment Over A year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35066252/code-to-calculate-minimum-monthly-credit-card-repayment-over-a-year)

Comment: In your first function, the `return` is indented too far - it should be after the `while` loop, not part of it.

Comment: On the first version `balace` is misspelled, which I think causes it to never break out of the `while` loop. Fixing that gives output `Lowest Payment: 90.0`